# How to get the token for register api in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http-headers

I am having the Url for Token generation,by using http post i am getting the token.now my problem was i have to use the generated token as header in register api(another api).

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchPost() async {
  print('feg');
  final response = await http.post(
    '/rest_api/gettoken&grant_type=client_credentials',
    headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Basic token"},
  );
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print("Result: ${response.body}");
  //return Post.fromJson(responseJson);
  return responseJson;
}
```

here i am getting the token i want to use that token to register api

```
  Future<Register> fetchPost() async {
  print('feg');
  final response = await http.post(
    'your base url/rest/register/register',
    headers: { HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer token",
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json"},
  );
  var   responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print("Result: ${response.body}");
  return Register.fromJson(responseJson);
}
```

this is the post method for register api,i want to use previously generated bearer token in above api headers.

Comment: When you get the token save it to [`SharedPreferences`](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) (a local Key-Value storage). You can retrieve the token from there whenever you need to call an API

Comment: Keep in mind the token is currently exposed. Using flutter_secure_storage with SharedPreferences suggested by Matias is a smarter approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save the generated token in the shared preferences. Then you can use it in any request later.

first add in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
```

then import it in your code:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

so when you get your token

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchPost() async {
  print('feg');
  final response = await http.post(
    '/rest_api/gettoken&grant_type=client_credentials',
    headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Basic token"},
  );
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print("Result: ${response.body}");
  //return Post.fromJson(responseJson);

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //now set the token inside the shared_preferences
  //I assumed that the token is a field in the json response, but check it before!!
  await prefs.setString('token',responseJson['token']);
  return responseJson;
}
```

and when you need to send the request just get the token from the `shared_preferences`:

```
Future<Register> fetchPost() async {
  print('feg');
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String token = prefs.getString('token');
  final response = await http.post(
    'your base url/rest/register/register',
    headers: { HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: token,
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json"},
  );
  var   responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print("Result: ${response.body}");
  return Register.fromJson(responseJson);
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much..@Sami Kanafani

Answer (score 1):

Another option, is use secure storage whit Keychain (Android) and Keystore (iOS)
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

Add in your pubspec.yaml

```dart
    dependencies:
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.2.1+1
```

And in your code, import library and save

```dart
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchPost() async {
final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  print('feg');
  final response = await http.post(
    '/rest_api/gettoken&grant_type=client_credentials',
    headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Basic token"},
  );
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print("Result: ${response.body}");
  //return Post.fromJson(responseJson);

  /// Write token in token key with security
  await prefs.write(key: 'token',value: responseJson['token']);
  return responseJson;
}
```

If you need read, use this code:

```dart
Future<Register> fetchPost() async {
final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  print('feg');
  String token = await storage.read(key: 'token');
  final response = await http.post(
    'your base url/rest/register/register',
    headers: { HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: token,
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json"},
  );
  var   responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print("Result: ${response.body}");
  return Register.fromJson(responseJson);
}
```